# How to read the mouse's appearance (pointer, resizing etc) in Win32

Tags: winapi, mouse

Is there a way to measure if the current mouse image displays that it is in resizing mode?

I am creating a horizontal slider which is simply a subclassed static (label).  When the user has the mouse cursor over the slider (the static control) and clicks and holds the left mouse button down (wm_lbuttondown)  I call Window's setcapture function.  I then call releasecapture when the user releases the mouse button (wm_lbuttonup).  My subclassed static control procedure is called onevent_label. WndProc handles messages for everything else.

The slider works well except when you complete one slide then immediately click the mouse to initiate a 2nd slide without first moving the mouse to a different region or clicking the mouse over another control.

I determined the problem is caused because the 2nd click, the wm_lbuttondown event, is being fired in wndproc (not onevent_label).  The mouse image appears to be in resize mode the entire time, however, I measure the mouse position in wndproc's wm_lbuttondown procedure and see it is one pixel to the left of my static label control, the slider.

A simple fix is to simply send the wm_lbuttondown message to the static control, however, I'd like to make wndproc's wm_lbuttondown procedure smart and only forward the message if appropriate.

I decided the best way to do this is to check to see if Windows is still displaying that the mouse is in resizing mode and that the cursor position is reasonably close to the static label.

I can't seem to find a way to measure if the mouse's image is a pointer (usual case) or showing it is looking to resize a control (right and left horizontal arrows).

Plan B is to only forward the message if the mouse position is within one or two pixels of the slider. In a perfect world I'd like to both know that the mouse displays the horizontal resize image and is within one or two pixels of the slider.

Thoughts? Comments?  Is there a way for me to determine if the mouse is displaying its horizontal resize image?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Who sets the mouse image appears to `resize` mode? If it was over the border of the window, someone else might be capturing mouse at that point. You can check for that with `GetCapture` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcapture

Comment: I realized that I created this problem for myself by not resetting the cursor (to IDC_ARROW) after I was done using it.  FYI to others that stumble on this question: I used gcl_hcursor and idc_sizewe to change the cursor to the horizontal resize and neglected to use gcl_hcursor and idc_arrow to reset.  For a vertical slider, use idc_sizens and reset to idc_arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re:  `Is there a way for me to determine if the mouse is displaying its horizontal resize image?` - here is how you can do that:

```
HCURSOR h = LoadCursor(NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_SIZEWE));
CURSORINFO ci = {sizeof CURSORINFO };
GetCursorInfo(&ci);
```

and compare `h` to `ci.hCursor`. All standard cursors are listed here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadcursora